# If $B$ is added to $A$, under what condition does the resultant vector have a magnitude equal to $A+B$?

Tags: vectors

If $B$ is added to $A$, under what condition does the resultant vector have a magnitude equal to $A+B$? Under what conditions is the resultant vector equal to zero?

My Attempt:
Let $\theta $ be the angle between $\vec {A}$ and $\vec {B}$. Then,

$$R=A+B$$
$$\sqrt {A^2+B^2+2A.B\cos \theta}=A+B$$
$$A^2+B^2+2A.B\cos \theta=A^2+B^2+2A.B$$
$$\cos \theta =1$$
$$\cos \theta = \cos 0$$
$$\theta =0°$$
The resultant have a magnitude $A+B$ when the angle between the vectors is $0°$. How do I solve the second part of the question.?

Comment: First point looks good. For the second one, all you need is $\,A+B=0 \iff A = -B\,$.

Comment: @dxiv, And how do I get that? Please elaborate.

Comment: First $|A|=|B|$, then $\cos\theta=-1$

Comment: @blue_eyed_... `how do I get that?` It's part of the definition of a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) that every vector $V$ has an additive inverse $-V$ such that $V + (-V) = 0\,$. Then, if $A+B=0$ you just add $(-B)$ to both sides of the equality and get $A=-B\,$.

Comment: Technically the answer to the question is "always," because if $A$ and $B$ are vectors then $A+B$ **is** the resultant of adding $B$ to $A$ and of course it has the same magnitude as itself. Presumably the person who asked the question meant to ask when the magnitude of $A+B$ is equal to the sum of the **magnitude** of $A$ and the **magnitude** of $B.$

Comment: What do you mean by a magnitude of $A+B$? Do you mean $\lvert A\rvert +\lvert B\rvert$?

Answer (score 1):

Though the obvious fact that $\vec B=-\vec A$, we can infer this from your previous expression:

$$A^2+B^2+2AB\cos\theta=0$$

If $A=0$, then trivially $B^2=0 \to B=0$, and viceversa, and the angle can be any value.

If $A,B\gt0$, this leads to:
$$
\cos\theta=-{A^2+B^2 \over 2AB}
$$

Knowing that $\cos(\cdot)$ must be bounded in [-1,1]:
$$
-1\le {A^2+B^2 \over 2AB}\le1\\
-2AB\le A^2+B^2\le2AB\\
-4AB\le (A-B)^2\le0\\
$$
which can only be true for $A=B$, and the angle in this case is $
\cos\theta=-{2\over2}=-1 \to \theta=\pi$